# Does referencing an iOS app delegate in a block create a copy of the delegate object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

Consider the following example:

```
- (void)exampleFunction
{
  AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  SomeClass *classObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
  [classObject someFunctionThatDoesBackgroundWorkAndCallsACompletionBlock:^(NSDictionary *results) {
    SomeNeatObject *object = appDelegate.someNeatObject;
    [object doSomeNeatStuff:results];
  }];
}
```

Making an assumption that the completion block is executed on the main/UI thread to avoid additional insanity, here's what I'm unsure of:

1. Does the appDelegate variable get copied onto the stack, as per normal block rules when referencing variables inside the block?
2. If yes to #1, is this a good / safe practice? I could see this possibly causing problems if you did this in a block that was subsequently dispatched to a GCD queue, as .someNeatObject could have changed state / gone to nil?

I realize that the appDelegate should not be overused, but it is useful for it to hold information about the current state of the application, such as Core Data-related objects if you use Apple's templates for initializing a Core Data stack (at least on iOS projects). That particular case (Core Data) has me concerned as much of that stack is not thread-safe nor is it a good idea to be copying it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't even put my CoreData stack in the app delegate.

Comment: "Does referencing an iOS app delegate in a block create a copy of the delegate object?" No. A block retains the root objects used in it, but it doesn't copy anything. Anything. Well, technically one might argue primitives are copied, but certainly no objects.

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure about that (thus why I asked the question) because ARC inherently copies the block, and according to apple's docs (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html) the block copies any instance variables referenced. So are objects only incremented, not copied?

Comment: @WayneHartman agreed but if you use Apple's default templates, that's where it gets stuck. Plus that was just an example :)

Comment: @MattS. I'm not sure where you're seeing anything about copying objects there. Perhaps under `__block` storage type? That copies the variable, i.e. the pointer, not the object itself.

Comment: @Kevin mmm yeah Sofi directed me down that path as well. I appreciate your thoughts on it and accepted his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example will not compile because delegate is not defined. I assume you mean "SomeNeatObject *object = appDelegate.someNeatObject;"

In this example, appDelegate is a variable, whose value will be captured by the block. It's no different than any other variable.

It's not unsafe, because [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] always returns the same thing, unless you change the delegate, which you probably don't.

The fundamental concepts here are: **appDelegate** is a *variable* which *points* (or refers) to an *object* (or instance) of type **AppDelegate**. In an iOS app there is one such instance, which is returned by [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]. If you create a reference to appDelegate inside a block, you are making a copy of the variable, not the object. So in your code's block:

```
SomeNeatObject *object = appDelegate.someNeatObject;
```

This is semantically the same as putting the following code in the block (casts omitted):

```
SomeNeatObject *object = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].someNeatObject;
```

The SomeNeatObjects being referred to are the same thing.

Slightly more advanced concept: any object has an address in memory (an integer, usually seen in hexadecimal). If two variables have the same hexadecimal value, they point to the same object. If they have different values, they point to different objects. In your example, appDelegate (outside block) and appDelegate (inside block) have the same value, therefore point to the same object.

If you were to do this:

```
AppDelegate * otherDelegate = [appDelegate copy];
```

Then you would be making a copy of the *object* pointed to by appDelegate. But don't do this, please.

Comment: Good catch on the appDelegate / delegate issue. Edited my code.

Comment: I'm not sure I necessarily agree with your statement though - if you copy the delegate - it copies the state of variables hanging on it, so wouldn't that mean variables won't necessarily match current versions?

Comment: Where did you copy the delegate? I don't see a call to the copy method.

Comment: It inherently copies unless you put __block in the pointer assignment line was my understanding?

Comment: No. __block means the variable can be modified in the block and the change would be visible outside the block.

Comment: No that's not right, see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html

Comment: Specifically Local variables declared within the lexical scope of the block, which behave exactly like local variables in a function.
Each invocation of the block provides a new copy of that variable. These variables can in turn be used as const or by-reference variables in blocks enclosed within the block.

Comment: A variable is not the same thing as an object. "appDelegate" is a variable that points to an AppDelegate object. When you say the block is making a copy of the variable "appDelegate", it is not copying the AppDelegate object it points to. The field someNeatObject is always the same field.

Comment: Accepting your answer - once I realized you meant it captured the pointer but not the underlying object. Maybe clarify your answer a bit to distinguish pointer vs objects.

Answer (score 2):

It's retain count does get incremented.  The remedy is to tag it with the `__weak` attribute:

```
- (void)exampleFunction {
  __weak AppDelegate *weakDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

  SomeClass *classObject = [[SomeClass alloc] init];
  [classObject someFunctionThatDoesBackgroundWorkAndCallsACompletionBlock:^(NSDictionary *results) {
    SomeNeatObject *object = weakDelegate.someNeatObject;
    [object doSomeNeatStuff:results];
  }];
}
```

Comment: Ugh I was worried that could happen. I'm curious to see what others would say, but I'm pretty sure that is the issue.

Comment: The retain count does get incremented, but this is most likely harmless.

Comment: Could you also toss __block onto the *appDelegate to avoid copying state?

Comment: @SofiSoftwareLLC Even though the lifetime of the app delegate is the entire lifetime of the app, why not use good coding practices all the time?  I'd argue that he shouldn't be abusing the app delegate as a place to store global state.

Comment: @MattS. `__block` only prevents incrementing the retain count when you are NOT using ARC.

Comment: @WayneHartman It seems to me that the retain count has nothing to do with what he is confused about.

Comment: @WayneHartman yes, but ARC inherently copies local variables as well as incrementing the retain count, which is what I'm worried about, if you look in Apple's documentation, it states local variables are copied when you reference them. So *appDelegate get's copied which could be a problem.

Comment: @MattS.  They are the same instance:

    NSLog(@"%p", self);
    
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        id<UIApplicationDelegate> delegate = self;
        NSLog(@"%p\t\t%p", self, delegate);
    });

This will print out the memory addresses of the variables.  They are all the same.